# 'JavaPackage' object is not callable pyspark 2.3.0 Anaconda Win10

Tags: pyspark, anaconda, py4j

I am starting with pySpark. I have installed it in anadonda in Win10. I have copied an example and when I execute the code, I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".\testingSpark.py", line 7, in <module>
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").getOrCreate()
File "D:\Windows\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 173, in getOrCreate
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
File "D:\Windows\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 331, in getOrCreate
SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
File "D:\Windows\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 118, in __init__
conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
File "D:\Windows\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 188, in _do_init
self._javaAccumulator = self._jvm.PythonAccumulatorV2(host, port)
TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

I have read about it, but I can find nothing to fix this error. Please, help me!

Comment: have you found the fix ?? am facing the same issue